# Web Application Updates: Caching old app

Tags: html, css, caching, grails, browser-cache

I've created a Grails web application and put it live for users to use. It makes use of caching + backbone tpl's etc.

The issue is, when I make changes to html/css and put the new version live: users can only see these updates if they clear their cache. How can I get it so I can force users to fetch a new copy when I make updates to these static files. I've thought of the following:

1 - Make http headers with expire set to midnight every night (so each day they fetch the static data again in the morning) - this would work nicely.

2 - Append a version to each static file I update.. for example   main-v1-1.css  and when I update this, change it to  main-v1-2.css  etc...

Any information would be handy, because currently when I push any slight html/css updates.. users are not seeing these new updates unless I get them to clear cache/refresh browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using  `cache-headers` plugin?  It can help you to control how the browser cache your contents [here](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers)

Comment: but I thought because it's cached... when the browser goes to index.html for example, it doesn't pickup the new html code or headers . I mean - If i previously had set the cache to 1month expire.. it's only going to grab the new header after 1 month.